# Powerline Network cuts out when Laptop Power Supply is plugged in

Tags: networking, laptop, power-supply, powerline-networking

I have a powerline adapter in my room because it's too far away from the router to get a good wifi signal. I have my main laptop plugged in and that works fine. However, I tried plugging in a second laptop and for some reason it's interfering with the powerline network because the network drops. I tried plugging the second laptop into a different power outlet, but when it was plugged in the network still dropped.

Comment: "that didn't do anything" is somewhat imprecise. Did the charger not receive power from the outlet? Did the laptop not receive power from the charger? Did the network drop out, or continue functioning? When describing a problem, *it helps to be as specific as possible.* I encourage you to [edit] your question to describe exactly what happened or did not happen, and how this was different from your expectations or desires.

Comment: Get a passthrough unit and use a multisocket through that. In theory, SMPS are noisy. I currently have something like half a dozen various PSUs on the same plug as my homeplug unit, and its fine. Also, the 'faster' the homeplug AV standard, the better it is about noise. Are you plugging in ethernet, power or a second homeplug AV unit?

Comment: "Get a passthrough unit and use a multisocket through that."
I don't actually know what any of that means. Can you explain or provide links?

I'm not super familiar with the intricate details of my powerline adapter, but I plugged my powerline ethernet cable into a switch, which I then connect my laptop to. I also have a whole bunch of things attached to the same wall socket. The powerline is attached directly to wall, but I have a power strip where everything else is attached.