# Wired Internet stops working when laptop is plugged in

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop, powerline-networking

I have wired Internet that runs via my electrical socket with a [Powerline Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication). It works perfectly **UNTIL** my laptop is plugged into another electrical socket.

As soon as the laptop charger is plugged in, the wired connection on my main PC drops, and I get the error "**Default gateway is not available**". I cannot see my router at all from my main PC when this occurs. As soon as I unplug the laptop from the electrical socket my Internet starts working again from my main PC with the wired connection.

What is going on here and how can I fix this?

---

### Other Detail

- I'm using only two **Belkin 200 Mbps Powerline Adapters**
- The powerline adaptors are both plugged directly into wall sockets with no power surge protectors
- I have tried both the Powerline Adapters and the laptop charger with multiple electrical sockets
- Below is a screen shot showing how my Powerline Adapter setup is configured

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how your setup is a little more?  Are you wiring your laptop to your router, or are you using a power-line adapter?  How is the PC connected?

Comment: Laptop connects via wireless connection. PC connects via the wired connection that goes through the plug socket. When the laptop is first connected the PC works for a minute or 2 but the speed drops continuously from 20mbs download speed all the way to 0.9mbs before it cuts out, like its draining the connection.

Comment: Do you mean a powerline adapter?  You have an ethernet connection plugged into a thing that plugs into a power socket, then another one somewhere else that has an ethernet connection to a router?

Comment: This is how the "wired" connection is setup: http://puu.sh/q0XBz/04b44d4cbd.png - The wireless connection is coming from the same router. Laptop Internet works via wireless and the PC works with wired connection UNTIL the laptop is plugged into the charger and then the Internet goes off on my main PC. Tried multiple sockets with the same results.

Comment: Yes, tried multiple sockets, tried removing the laptop battery, turning ipv6 off on both computers, running the PC in safe mode, changing the power setting on the laptop. None of these have changed what happens.

Comment: How many and is that the only kinds you have connected? Just two only?

Comment: Just to be 100% certain, does the laptop connect with one of those power line adapters or not?

Comment: The laptop connects to the Internet wireless-ly. It plugs into a charger which goes directly into a plug socket. It does not use a powerline adaptor. The powerline adaptors are both plugged directly into wall sockets with no power surge protectors. I have tried these in multiple sockets as well as the laptop charger.

Comment: It sounds like your charger is either poorly designed or malfunctioning.  When it starts to charge your laptop, it should not affect the rest of the wiring in your house at all.  I'd try putting it behind a surge protector to see if that helps with it.

Comment: The laptop is not even turned on. The Internet on my desktop PC begins to die as soon as the laptop is plugged in. Here are 2 tests I did before (http://puu.sh/q0ZhM/8d14ac078a.jpg) and after (http://puu.sh/q0ZiE/0ce0b74c01.jpg) plugging the laptop in.

Comment: If the laptop is plugged in and the battery is charging, it's on enough for the charger.  If the laptop is plugged in, but not charging, it's still going to be active as the laptop will pull power from the charger before it pulls it from the battery.  LEDs and the BIOS on the laptop will pull an ever so slight amount of power, and that may be all that's needed to have it send feedback into your network.

Comment: The laptop does charge when plugged in. Here are some images I took of said charger: http://puu.sh/q104B/1be0be688a.jpg http://puu.sh/q105X/34c55a36ab.jpg

Comment: Instead of adding more details in the comments (which will be deleted) you should edit the question to include that

Comment: I can't - it tells me I need more than 10 reputation to add more links.

Comment: Try using an extension cord on your charger (the longer the better), just as a test. If your charger is putting a great deal of noise on the electrical lines, an extension cord will filter out the noise to some degree; possibly sufficiently for the link to stay up. If the extension cord makes things better at all, it means you should look for a replacement charger. Another thing to try is a different electrical outlet circuit - one that is on a different circuit breaker - It's not clear if you tried that or not. This will also minimize the noise that gets to the powerline adapters.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/952861/powerline-network-cuts-out-when-laptop-power-supply-is-plugged-in

Comment: I bit the bullet and bought a brand new charger, just hope it fixes the problem. It will arrive tomorrow so will respond and update if it works. Thanks for all the comments so far guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the model of the power-line adapters you're using, you may not be able to have more than the two nodes on the system.  There are some that will allow up to 64, but without knowing the model number of your adapters, the best I can do for you is guess.  As for your speed issue, this would all depend on how much bandwidth each device is using as the maximum speeds of the power-line adapters is shared between all of the other devices, as well as the fact that only one device can be communicating at a time if I'm not mistaken.  Another thing to keep in mind is that anyone close to you could potentially use the same technology to get onto your network, so use the builtin encryption for the system if you're able.  I had more than three nodes in my house at one time, and after the fourth was put in place, the system would not work properly for some of the other nodes.  My solution was to run a cable to my office and just get LAN speeds from the router.

Edit: I forgot to mention that these devices should NOT be plugged into a surge protector or battery backup.  Surge protectors can actually interfere with the signals that the power-line adapters are sending out when they're conditioning the lines.

Comment: I am using the Belkin 200MBPS Powerline Adapters.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the laptop charger for a new Toshiba made one and the problem resolved itself. I can only assume the old charger was putting noise onto the connection.